# Cannot fetch data from google-cloud-firestore correctly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uikit, avplayer

No problems with fetching Title and Subtitle. Problems are with downloading of images and streaming the video. I really appreciate your help friends. I just want to learn how to implement it correctly and what to use, get data method or listener? Does it need grammatical changes of my code or a pair of code lines?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Combine

class ListOfVideoLessonsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()
    
    private var viewModel = VideosViewModel()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
  
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
       self.title = "Video Lessons"
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
        cancellable = viewModel.$videos.sink { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("videos count = ", viewModel.videos.count)
        return viewModel.videos.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let video = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        //configure cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = video.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = video.lessonName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
       
        
        let image = UIImage(data: video.imageData)
        cell.imageView?.image = image...
        imageName!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        
        return cell
    }
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        
        playVideo(at: indexPath)
        
    }
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
            cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
            cell.detailTextLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
            

            }

    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
            
            }

    }
  
        func playVideo(at indexPath: IndexPath){
            let selectedVideo = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
            let videoURL = URL(string: selectedVideo.fileURL)
            player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
            playerViewController.player = player
            
            
          self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                self.playerViewController.player?.play()
            })
           
        }
}
```

This is the VideosViewModel which supposed to download data from firestore database and translate into local file names if I am not mistaken.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore


class VideosViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var videos = [Video]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    
    static func downloadImage(withURL url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ _image:UIImage?)->()) {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, url, error in
        var downloadedImage:UIImage?
            
        if let data = data {
            downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(downloadedImage)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    
   func fetchData() {
        db.collection("videos").addSnapshotListener { [self] (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No Documents")
                return  
            }
            
            self.videos = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Video in
               let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let imageName = data["imageName"]as? URL ?? ""
                let lessonName  = data["lessonName"] as? String ?? ""
                let fileURL  = data["fileURL"] as? String ?? ""
       
                print(data)


                return Video(name: name, imageName: imageName, lessonName: lessonName, fileURL: fileURL)
                
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

````
import Foundation

struct Video {
    var name: String
    var imageName: Data
    var lessonName: String
    var fileURL: String
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIU5O.png
````

Comment: The question is kind of broad and unclear and the code has a LOT of white space - can you remove some of those blank lines and correct the formatting so it's easier to read? Is the question about - *fetch title and subtitle* - or is it about - *problems with downloading images* - or is it about - *problems with streaming videos*?

Comment: You need to break this down into one specific question. And if you have other questions then you need to make those separate questions. Do you need to know how to fetch images from Storage? Do you need to know where to fetch images? Do you need to know how to coordinate observable objects with data fetching? Be specific.